# 3D cylinder from function with varying radius

Tags: python, 3d, surface

I want to create a cylinder (Hyperboloid) from a function that varies with the radius. So what I have is a function:

```
def f(x):
     return np.sqrt(1+(x/constant)**(2))
```

and of course in y-direction. All I want is, that this function spins around and looks like a hyperboloid (see figure). I created these surface plots, but not with a function like f(x).

[image]

Comment: So how *did* you create this surface plot?

Comment: Your function ``f(x)`` should go where `z3` is in the example you stated below.

Comment: Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this, but it is not 100% correct. At x,y=0 the function should be =w0*np.sqrt(1)=w0=1.701. That is not the case.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, cos, sin, sqrt, outer, ones
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, pi, 100)
one_v = ones(100)

w0=1.701
lamb=0.90846
d_in1=45
foc1=38.35
zR=np.pi*w0**(2)/(lamb)


x=np.linspace(-30,30,100)
def f(x):
    return w0*np.sqrt(1+(x/zR)**(2))

# Hyperboloid
v = 2*v/pi - 1
x3 = 6 * outer(cos(u), sqrt(1 + v**2))
y3 = 6 * outer(sin(u), sqrt(1 + v**2)) 
z3 = f(x)
ax.plot_surface(x3, y3, z3, rstride=5, cstride=5, cmap='Spectral',
                linewidth=0.5)

# Fix aspect ratio and axes details
#ax.set_xlim(-13, 13)
#ax.set_ylim(-13, 13)
#ax.set_zlim(-13, 13)
#ax.view_init(elev=35, azim=-45)
#plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('Gaussian curvature.svg', transparent=True)
plt.show()
```